# how to use create QTthread periodically to send stuff?

Tags: c++, qt

i'm new to qt stuff, in my project i need to send some stuff periodically using threads. so the only way in qt is to use qttimer and qtthreads such that on every timeout i will create a thread to send out my stuff? is this the logical way to do it? thanks!

Comment: sorry, or should it be timer inside the thread, meaning that when i create the thread in the run() i create the qttimer to send the stuff periodically?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a QThread if you are using a timer. QTimer already works asynchronously so launching a thread from it wouldn't be useful.

Comment: thanks for the reply. what if im suppose to use a thread to send out my stuff periodically? do i have to use some sleep func in the run-loop to send my stuff out? or is there better solutions? thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you *have* to use a QThread, then the simplest way is to have a loop and a sleep function. After the call to the sleep function, create your thread and launch it. Note that while the application is on the loop, the user interface is going to be frozen. If you don't have a UI it's not a problem, but if you do, you'd be better off using a QTimer.

Comment: thx for your reply. can i create a thread and in its loop i put the sleep func such that i will keep sending out my stuff periodically in then loop itself? i'm putting the thread to sleep not my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer in a separate thread.

In the thread's `run` function, create a `QTimer` and set it to trigger your desired slot. Then call `exec` to start a message loop in the thread to handle signals.

Comment: will that be better or more accurate compared to using sleep in the thread's run func? thanks!

Comment: @craftace: I think it's cleaner. One issue with sleeping in the run method is exiting elegantly, and using `exec` handles that for you. To get real accuracy you need real-time functionality and that's pretty tricky. If you're not doing that then using a QTimer should be at least as accurate.